# HowTo: componentDidMount and onclick javascript issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, prisma

So, I have button clicks which are programmatically activated on componentDidMount. The issue I'm having is that because there are multiple button clicks this is causing the desired outcome of one of the intended clicks, which updates a Prisma database, to be completely skewed.

What I want to happen is for `updateItem` to be triggered once when the page is loaded. What's the best way to achieve this?:

```html
componentDidMount(){          
document.getElementById("updateItemButton").click();
document.getElementById("toggleCartButton").click();
}


    render() {
        return (
        <Query query={SINGLE_ITEM_QUERY} variables={{ id: this.props.itemid }}>

                return (
                    <Mutation mutation={TOGGLE_CART_MUTATION}>
                        {(toggleCart) => {
                            return (
                                <Mutation
                                mutation={UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION}
                                variables={{
                                    id: this.props.itemid,
                                    quantity: itemDetails.quantity - this.props.quantity, 
                                }}
                                refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }]}
                                >
                                {(updateItem, { loading, error }) => (
                                    <>
                                    <div><button type="button" hidden id="updateItemButton" disabled={loading} onClick={updateItem} /></div>
                                    <div><button type="button" hidden id="toggleCartButton" disabled={loading} onClick={toggleCart} /></div>
                                    </>
                                )}
                                </Mutation>
                            );
                        }}
                    </Mutation>
                );
            }}
        </Query>
        );
    }
```

I tried

> onclick={(x) => {x}}

but this only caused the functions not to fire at all.

Comment: Have you tried just calling the updateItem function on the componentDidMount?

Comment: @Dmitriy You'll have to forgive me, I'm new to the react world and am still finding my feet. Did you mean as, this.updateItem? If so, nothing happened.

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant, run this.updateItem() when the component mounts. Where do you have the updateItem function defined? if nothing happens are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: @Dmitriy As shown in the code, the methods become exposed after each mutation, i.e. {(toggleCart) => {}}. No errors were displayed in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

1. Calling `click` function on the button will not trigger React's `onClick` handlers
2. Directly accessing DOM is fundamentally not how you do things in React. This is very bad practice.

> What I want to happen is for updateItem to be triggered once when the
>   page is loaded. What's the best way to achieve this?:

You can call `updateItem` method directly instead of clicking on the button programatically.

<strike>**Update # 1:**
e.g. 
You can call it directly in JSX where its available.</strike>

```
{(updateItem, { loading, error }) => {
    // do whatever you want with updateItem
    updateItem();
    // return JSX
    return (
        <>
        <div><button type="button" hidden id="updateItemButton" disabled={loading} onClick={updateItem} /></div>
        <div><button type="button" hidden id="toggleCartButton" disabled={loading} onClick={toggleCart} /></div>
        </>
    );
}}
```

Remember you can write any valid JavaScript inside curly braces.

**Update # 2:**

Your main issue is **How to execute a mutation on mount in react-apollo?**

You can create a component `MutationOnMount` and can use it within your Mutation function to take advantage of `componentDidMount`.

```
class MutationOnMount extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.mutation(); // Run mutation on Mount
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Now your code will look like this:

```
{(updateItem, { loading, error }) => (
    <MutationOnMount mutation={updateItem} />
    <div><button type="button" hidden id="updateItemButton" disabled={loading} onClick={updateItem} /></div>
    <div><button type="button" hidden id="toggleCartButton" disabled={loading} onClick={toggleCart} /></div>
)}
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1939#issuecomment-404616804

Previous approach (Update # 1) was problematic because we were setting state in render method. This should never be done. Render method should be pure without any side effects. Otherwise you will face infinite loop issue because of re-rendering.

Comment: "You can call updateItem method directly instead of clicking on the button programatically." - As a complete newbie to react how and where would I do this exactly, as the methods are exposed only after the mutations take place? I tried this.updateItem  from within componentDidMount but nothing happened.

Comment: Of course `updateItem` will not work in componentDidMount because it is not available there. You can call it directly from JSX

Comment: For some reason calling the methods as per your description is causing an infinite loop to happen, which eventually hangs my browser. There is a warning issued about satisfying functions within a render and then it hangs.

Comment: Main issue is `How to execute a mutation on mount?`. I have updated my answer